# Is there a way to observe all network response in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, http-headers, httpresponse, saml-2.0

If it's an api request that I call myself, I know I can just pass {observe: "response"} to access its headers.

However, in my case, I got a requirement that need me to redirect from my Angular app to third-party site.
The site have its login page which will redirect back to my Angular app after user is authenticated and send token along in its headers.

Is there anyway I can access that network response's headers in ngOnInit?
I'm looking for a way to subscribe to all network response to get that result, or is there any other way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please look into interception https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: @AviadP. 
I might misunderstood, but I've tried using interceptor and only got responses of api request I called myself.
In my case, it isn't api that I called, but is attributes added after the site redirect back to me.

Comment: You cannot intercept calls that are issued by other tabs or pages or apps. Browsers isolate your page from other pages.

Comment: It actually a SAMLResponse. The third-party redirect to my page and attach that SAMLResponse to the headers of my page. 
I didn't wanna get headers from other pages, I wanna get it from my own. I'm just not the one who request it.
There is the response in network tab in Chrome's developer tool.

Comment: Any headers sent to request the angular app itself will not be visible to angular. The request headers are sent to the web server, and the app is sent back as a response from the web server to the browser.

Comment: Aviad’s comment still stands. The only way a third party redirect can pass information to your app is through GET params in the redirect url.

Comment: Thanks Aviad. I see your point there. I might misunderstand that since I config the app to re-render immediately, but the network response still linger on.